# Popup header.php

Tags: html, wordpress, popup, popupwindow

I want insert popup in header.php.
I want a popup button with an image. 
Example with screen:

[image: https://gyazo.com/fdda47a92f015c54f58cc10088cfcb23]

I want that user click on button "contatta il dj" popup open in window automatically.

In header.php this is one code:

```
<a class="tile" style="background-image: url( 'http://s8.postimg.org/az38crnn5/party_dj_adelaide_icon1.png' ); background-position: center 13px; background-repeat: no-repeat;" href="http://www.specialradio1.altervista.org/contattaildj">
<span class="tile-title">CONTATTA IL DJ</span></a>
```

But I want a popup, help me please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a popup **HTML**

   ```
     <div class='popup_window'>
         Put Your Content Here
     </div>
   ```
2. **CSS**

   ```
      .popup_window{ display: none; position: fixed; top: 10%; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); }
   ```
3. **JS**

   ```
   $(".tile-title").on("click", function(){
       $(".popup_window").
     });
   ```

Comment: Grazie molto, ma non capisco: 1) creo popup con blocco note? Dove inserisco il file? nei temi cartella? 2) js, '' titolo tegola '' Devo cambiare con il nome del tasto?

Comment: If you want on all the pages, add to footer.php, else add to your corresponding page.

Comment: What should I write in content your here?
2)code popup HTML i can insert in header.php or create new file with notepad?
3)JS i must change something? (tile-title) i chage with name of button? 
Thank you for help

Comment: Replace "Put Your Content Here" whatever(text, image, html code) you want to show in the popup, you can insert it in the header.php, place the JS in a JS file, must be there in your theme, and yepp you can change the name of the button, use the same class attribute. https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: working but the page when i open 
is blank.
screen: https://gyazo.com/addb4600f5e76181d28648f68ce06af0 Please help me

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/ Use this plugin, go through the screenshots, and insert the above code, as required.

Comment: Sorry but i am not english,you can tell me which of the three to use in javascript?

Comment: JS to be used in Javascript, CSS to be used in CSS, and HTML in HTML, for the JS use jQuery before you insert thee code. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js